# Restricting Users to only edit their data in SharePoint edit form

Tags: sharepoint, view

I'm trying to restrict the Edit List Form in SharePoint to only allow users to edit their own data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
James

Comment: What is "their own data" (entire list item, certain fields..)? Also, what specifies the item belongs to a certain user (item was created by the user, assigned to them..)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to restrict the entire list item to the user who created it:

1. Click List Settings
2. Click Advanced Settings
3. Set Edit Access to "Only their own"

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to allow them to edit only items they've created, you can use a SharePoint Designer Workflow and the custom workflow activities from here: http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

... to modify the permissions on the item when it's created, allowing the user who created it Contribute access and everyone else Read.